Private Methods and ActiveModel::Validator
I have a custom validator I am using for two models with very similar needs:
class GameSettingsValidator < ActiveModel::Validator
  def validate(record)
    record.check_max_players
  end
end

In each model I am using validates_with GameSettingsValidator, on: :create. However, the check_max_players method is private in both models and it is failing. I know I can use send or move the method into public. However, I have typically avoided using send for this type of behavior and putting a method into public just for validation feels dirty. When I originally wrote this I thought ActiveModel::Validator would have access to the private methods like a concern would but I was wrong in that assumption. I curious what others believe would be the "clean" way to go about implementing this?

Seems like you could just create a Concern and add all the common logic and functionality (including validations) into that module and then include it in the classes where it is needed.

check_max_players seems to hold some logic for the validation, so why not moving it into the validator ?

Agree with @maxence
If this falls under validation scope, it should be moved to the validator—unless it's also used elsewhere
